# SAS 9.3 do loop within proc sql select

Tags: sas, proc-sql

i would like to join the dataset like the following by using do loop inside the proc sql: i have macro variables yymm0-yymm4; yymm0=1505; yymm11=1501.

this is the code without do-loop:

```
proc sql;
 create table output as
 select var1, var3 from data1 where a=1 union
 select var1, var3 from data2 where a=1 union
 select var1, var3 from data3 where a=1 union
 select var1, var3 from data4 where a=1
quit;
run;
```

How can i do it if i got 12 datasets which name of the datasets are data1-data12?

Comment: SAS cannot reference more than a couple of dozen tables in a single SQL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SAS 9.3 I guess, you can do this:

```
data output;
set data: (keep = a var1 var3);
where a=1;
drop a;
run;
```

where `data:` will match all of  your data1, data2...

Of course in SQL equivalent this does an `union all`, not `union`.

Before SAS 9.3 or when the list if not a simple prefix, build a macro variable to hold your list, e.g.:

```
%let mylist=;
proc sql noprint;
select catt(libname, '.', memname) into :mylist separated by ' '
from dictionary.tables where libname="your libname" and memname  like 'your_pattern%'
;
quit;
```

Then just use `&mylist` instead of `data:` .

Comment: many thanks @vasja, what if the dataset name is a dynamic macro variables? like rls&yymm0..data&yymm0. 0-11 ?

Comment: If you'll always change question after an answer, the old answers won't make sense

Comment: okay. i am sorry about that. maybe i should ask another question